# CBdException: Column 'id' cannot be null

Tags: assets, database, assetfilemodel

I receive the following error only when I clear the cache:

[image]

When I try to rebuild the image index, all of my image paths go missing.
I'm not sure what caused this error but I do need to fix it.

I've checked my image transforms and everything is named correctly. I even tried to delete and re-add and still nothing. I'm getting this same error on another one of my craft sites when I empty the cache.

I have no idea what's causing it.

I did come across this post:
[CDbException: Column not found](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/14739/cdbexception-column-not-found)

I read through the comments but no solution has been posted. I did a db search for CONSTRAINT or FOREIGN KEY and have both.

Any and all help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

---

UPDATE!!!

**Things I tested and found**:

I looked at the assettransformindex in the database and it was empty.

I ran an INSERT statement to populate the rows with proper information - it inserted successfully.
I refreshed the site, the CBd exception was gone.

I cleared the cache, minus the image transform index and the site still worked perfectly.

I cleared the cache with image transform index selected and it stripped everything from the DB.

If I try to upload an asset that uses the transform, it throws the CBd exception again and clears the DB.

I hope this information helps...
Thank you in advance.

Comment: My guess is there is an asset source path not setup somewhere correct.  Can you upload Asset successfully though the asset index page?

Comment: Hi Brad. I'm able to upload an asset through the asset index page. I just double checked the asset paths and they all appear correct. When I try to update the asset index, I get the following error: "The following files could not be found. Should they be deleted from the index?" -- but those assets are all accessible from the front-end.

Comment: Hrm... might be easier if you shared your file system directory structure and how you've got your local Asset sources defined.

Comment: @BradBell can I send you a copy of the site + db? If so, how can I send that info to you?

Comment: If you want to zip them up and send them to support@craftcms.com, we can take a look at them.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was because several tables were missing the MySQL auto-increment flag for their `id` integer primary keys.